# Workforce scheduling problem

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, scheduling

I am working on a employee scheduling problems (assigning shifts to temporary workers) by modeling it as a MIP. There is a one shift per day constraint for the employees. There are overnight shifts and need to take care of the day boundaries and employee rest periods -- for example an employee working between 8pm on a day till 2am the next day can not start their shift the next day without having a rest time of x hours. So in summary, there are overlapping shifts and need to choose a single shift from the set of overlapping shifts. There can be multiple such overlapping groups for a single employee. We have modeled it as mutual exclusive constraints (sum of all variables in an overlap group can be at most one). But the problem is that in certain cases,the number of variables in such constraints is quite big (1000+) and these are all binary variables. So the problem is getting hard to solve pretty fast. I wanted to know if there is any other way to model this or can we simplify in any way. Thank you.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4812413/mutual-exclusivity-variables-in-mixed-integer-programming-problems

Comment: Sorry, I did not know both or and math stackexchange are accessible by both communities. I will take care of this going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a side-constrained network formulation in which you have a node for each employee-day-shift and a directed arc if the employees are the same, the days are consecutive, and the shifts do not overlap. You will also need for each employee a dummy source node and a dummy sink node. Now for each employee you want to find a directed source-sink path, which by construction of the network will visit each day exactly once.  So far, this is a pure network problem for each employee, but you presumably also have side constraints across employees so each day-shift has enough employees to cover the demand.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Gurobi to solve our scheduling MIP. I am not sure how to fit this network formulation into a MIP model. As you pointed out correctly there are other side constraints like demand coverage, employee min/max daily/weekly hours, consistency of shifts, and so on.

Comment: You will need a binary decision variable for each arc and a “flow balance” equality constraint for each node.

Comment: My current model has employee-shift binary variables. With these network problem related constraints I will have to introduce binary variables for all the arcs. So looks like will have to introduce these new binary variables in lieu of the original employee-shift binary variables. So now all other constraints like demand coverage, minimum weekly hours, etc. will be defined in terms of these arc binary variables.Is that correct? Also, I am trying to understand why this formulation is better than the original formulation with mutually exclusive variables for non overlapping shifts.

Comment: You can link the original variables to the arc variables via equality constraints. A pure network problem would have the total unimodularity property and hence require no branching. If you have only a small percentage of side constraints, the resulting branch-and-cut tree can often still be small.

Comment: So performancewise is there any difference between removing the original variables and formulating everything using only the arc variables vs keeping the originals and linking them to the arc variables? From the implementation perspective retaining original variables might be easier and faster.

Comment: If the original variables appear in several places, explicitly replacing them with sums of arc variables everywhere would make the problem denser than it needs to be, hurting the performance.

Comment: Makes sense. I was trying to work out a toy problem with these arc variabels and the flow balance equality constraints. If we decide to model this as a pure network problem, we are going to have significantly more (more than twice) decision variables as compared to the current model with shift-worker assignment variables. Does that affect the solver performance?

Comment: This is one of those seemingly counterintuitive situations where making the problem bigger can lead to big performance gains.  For more details, see my blog post: https://blogs.sas.com/content/operations/2015/04/03/the-traveling-baseball-fan-problem/

Comment: Can you provide an intution on why it is so? Also, if I have shifts spanning multiple days how do I create the arc variables as there is a clear day boundary.

Comment: The intuition is in my previous comment about total unimodularity.  You have a directed arc from (e,d,s1) to (e,d+1,s2) if day d and shift s1 ends with enough rest time before day d+1 and shift s2 starts.

Comment: Sorry missed the link in the previous comment. Thanks. For the multiday shift, so let's say for a shift s1 spanning 24+ hours starting on day d1, if there is a rest period of a whole day d2, do we create an arc from s1 to shifts starting on day 3 directly?

Comment: Yes, the arcs correspond to possible pairs of consecutive shifts.  So your "one shift per day" requirement is really "at most one shift per day" instead?

Comment: Yes, it is "at most one shift per day" even without multi-day shifts. There are some use cases where if a multi-day shift is selected for a worker there won't be any shift for that worker until the worker is well rested (rest period is predefined) for the next shift.

Comment: OK, then you will need arcs from (e,d1,s1) to (e,d2,s2), where d2 >= d1 (not just d2 = d1+1).  But do not include such arcs where employee e must work in some intermediate d3 with d1 < d3 < d2.

Comment: got it, thanks. I reformulated our problem with these new arc variabels and flow balance constraints, seems pretty straight forward. Thanks for your valuable inputs. One last question -- for this workforce scheduling problem why is network flow formulation the state-of-the-art? Why people still use the linear programming as the first choice?

Comment: Glad to help.  Please mark my answer as accepted.  A network formulation is often not the first approach that comes to mind because the resulting decision variables correspond to multiple decisions whereas the typical modeling paradigm involves a one-to-one correspondence between decision variables and decisions.

Comment: Hello, we have a new requirement from a customer for a multiple shifts per day constraint instead of one shift per day. I was trying to model it as a network formulation like one shift per day. Althought it's not that hard to model this one has more complexity due to overnight shifts overlap and separation with the day bounderies. Do you think it would be a good direction for this type of constraints?

Comment: Yes, the same network-based approach will work. Each node corresponds to the start of some shift, and each arc corresponds to starting a shift at each endpoint and working no shifts between those two shifts. You now need to allow arcs from (e,d,s) to (e,d2,s2) where d2 might be the same day d. But you still define an arc only if it’s possible to work both shifts with enough rest between.

Comment: Sounds good. How to deal with the at-most one shift per day or at most k shifts per day constraint with the network formulation that you suggested. By design the network formulation will force to take a shift per day in one shift per day or all the consecutive shifts in a directed path for multiple shifts per day.

Comment: The "at most one shift per day" requirement is enforced by omission of any arc between nodes that share a day.  For a more general "at most k shifts per day" requirement, you can include a shift count as part of each node definition.  The count starts at 1 each day and increases by 1 when you traverse an arc between nodes on the same day, and any node that has count k cannot have an arc to another node on the same day.

Comment: But that still forces me to select shifts in a consecutive manner, right? For example if there is an arc from a shift (8am to 11am) to a shift (11am to 2pm) that has an arc to a shift (2pm to 4pm), there is no way I can omit the shift (11am to 2pm) and have the other two in final schedule, right? I can not omit that arc altogether as I don't know which combination is optimal.

Comment: Also, it does not allow me to have a liberty to choose days that a worker is allocated a shift -- from a week a worker might have a pattern of at most 5 working days and two rest days but with this formulation I can't leave it to the optimizer to choose those days.

Comment: The network definition includes as arcs all feasible pairs of shifts that can be performed consecutively by that employee.  If you want to allow 8am and 2pm without working 11am, you would define an arc from 8am to 2pm.  The solver decides whether to use that arc or not.

Comment: But I don't know which ones are going to be optimal so can't decide a priori which arcs to omit -- what I want instead is for the solver to choose the optimal set from all the possible shifts a worker can take.

Comment: You don't decide what's optimal.  You decide what's possible (the allowed arcs), and the solver decides what's optimal (which allowed arcs to use).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151780/discussion-between-sdc-and-robpratt).

Answer (score 0):

We typically handle "overlapping shifts", "minimum X hours between two shifts" and/or "one shift per day" as separate constraints.
This is because in some cases they aren't always all hard constraints. Some of them can be soft constraints with a heavy weight.

We **avoid binary variables** by given each shift a variable to hold an employee, instead of creating a variable for each shift-employee combination. So if there are 1000 shifts and 200 employees, there are 1000 variables with 200 values. Not 200 000 variables with 2 values. That's a huge difference in search space (`200^1000` ~ `2^8000` versus `2^200000`).

For what it's worth, here's an implementation of those constraints in Timefold (not a MIP solver):

```
Constraint noOverlappingShifts(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEachUniquePair(Shift.class, 
                    Joiners.equal(Shift::getEmployee),
                    Joiners.overlapping(Shift::getStart, Shift::getEnd))
            .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                    EmployeeSchedulingConstraintProvider::getMinuteOverlap)
            .asConstraint("Overlapping shift");
}

Constraint atLeast10HoursBetweenTwoShifts(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEachUniquePair(Shift.class,
                    Joiners.equal(Shift::getEmployee),
                    Joiners.lessThanOrEqual(Shift::getEnd, Shift::getStart))
            .filter((firstShift, secondShift) -> Duration.between(firstShift.getEnd(), secondShift.getStart()).toHours() < 10)
            .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                    (firstShift, secondShift) -> {
                        int breakLength = (int) Duration.between(firstShift.getEnd(), secondShift.getStart()).toMinutes();
                        return (10 * 60) - breakLength;
                    })
            .asConstraint("At least 10 hours between 2 shifts");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. For us constraint programming is not on table so need to think about simplifying the MIP model only. I think your variable creation also works better for a CP model, but not sure if it would have the same advantage for a MIP. In fact I think having shift-employee binary variables seems a better approach for a MIP?

Comment: We use metaheuristics instead of CP, but some principles are the same. Yes, for a MIP approach, binary variables make sense.