Network formulation based side constraints for a workforce scheduling problem
For a workforce scheduling problem, I have formulated the "at most one shift per day" constraint as a network formulation based side constraint (with other constraints like demand coverage, budget, min/max weekly/daily hours, min rest days etc.). For each worker, there is a set of eligible shifts (meaning the worker is available and qualified). Each shift is a node in the network. The directed arcs in the network are as follows:

from source node to each shift node
from each shift node to the sink node
from shift s1 to shift s2 if s2 is a possible shift after s1

I have linked these new arc variables to the worker-shift-assignment variables that already exist in the model.
While testing this new model I noticed that the worker shift network is too dense (each shift has a very large set of other valid shifts) and edge heavy. Even for a smaller problem (about a few thousand candidate shifts and a handful of workers, the number of arc variables grows to millions), the solver (Gurobi in this case) struggles to find a solution. Is there a way to reduce the arc variables?

You might consider omitting “long” arcs that would schedule a worker for two consecutive shifts that are far apart in time.

But would it not result in less flexibility and a suboptimal solution?

Yes, if you don’t have such a restriction in the original problem, then omitting these arcs  might yield a worse objective value. But this is a reasonable approach to get a good starting solution.

The question calls the network a formulation of an "at most one shift per day" constraint, but then you say arcs represent shifts following other shifts. There seems to be a disconnect here.

@prubin The arcs join shifts from different days.

@RobPratt If so, that's different from "one shift per day" (which presumably is enforced elsewhere in the model).

Is the number of shift pairs $(s_1, s_2)$ where $s_2$ is not allowed after $s_1$ substantially smaller than the number of legal pairs (arcs in the network)?

Adding link to previous question for context: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/11279/workforce-scheduling-problem
